# Natural grammar for expressing someone is part of two groups

Tags: grammar

I'm having trouble finding the most natural grammar to describe someone being part of two groups. For example:

```
He is the only person who lives in this state that works for that company.
```

Here is my best guess:

```
その会社に勤めてる人で、この州に住んでるのは彼だけです。
```

Is this natural? Is there other ways to express this that would sound better?

Comment: It's perfect to me. To be more formal, 勤めてる/住んでる → 勤めて**いる** / 住んで**いる**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your sentence:

> その会社に勤めてる人で、この州に住んでるのは彼だけです。

sounds good to me. I think you can also say:

> その会社に勤めていてこの州に住んでいる｛人は、彼だけです。/人と言えば、彼しかいません。｝

And, I might say (a bit more simply?):

> その会社に勤めて(い)てこの州に住んで(い)るのは彼(orあの人)だけです。

without using 人.

Examples using this structure:

> - あの日ここに泊まっていて田中さんと面識があったのは、鈴木さんだけです。
> - カナダ出身でこの町に１０年以上住んでいる人と言えば、ジョンさんしかいない。

---

A few more variants I can think of are:

> - その会社に勤めて(い)る人の[中]{なか}で、この州に住んで(い)るのは彼だけです。
> - その会社に勤めて(い)る人のうち(で)、この州に住んで(い)るのは彼だけです。

(Although it would depend on the context, using その人/あの人 or the person's name instead of 彼 would usually sound even more natural.)

Comment: 文語的な・硬い感じになってもよければ、「かつ」とか「なおかつ」っていう言葉もあります。「その会社に勤めていて、 **かつ/なおかつ**この州に住んでいるのは～～」

Answer (score 1):

Is this natural?  --> Yes, but I wouldn't reverse the order. ( or maybe what you have is more logical ... interesting question. )

この州に住んでる人で、その会社に勤めてるのは彼だけです。
この州に住んでいて、その会社に勤めてる人は彼だけです。

この州の住人で、その会社に勤めてるのは彼だけです。

この州の住人で、ＡＡＡ社員は彼だけです。

ＢＢＢ州住人で、ＡＡＡ社員は彼だけです。
ＢＢＢ州住人でＡＡＡ社員なのは彼だけです。
ＢＢＢ州住人のＡＡＡ社員は彼だけです。

彼が・・・
first in the sentence seems slightly awkward.

彼が唯一のＢＢＢ州住人のＡＡＡ社員です。
彼がただ一人の・・・

- He is the only person who lives in this state that works for that company.
- He is the only person who lives in this state and works for that company.

In my mind,  these two sentences are the same, so what you have in the OP seems like reversed order.

Comment: In the first line, did you mean you "would" reverse the order?